# Javascript array of objects manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
 homepage: function (req, res) {
        var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
        var now = new Date();

        sequelize.query('SELECT "AmountLoaned" ,"ExpectedRecovery","ActualRecovery" FROM dashboard.tbldailyrecoverystatistics').then(function (data) {

            res.view('homepage', {
                data: data,

            });

        }).catch(function (error) {

            console.log(error);
            res.json({error: true});
        });

    }
};
```

```html
  .col-lg-3
            .alert.alert-danger.text-center
                i.fa.fa-calendar.fa-3x
                b

        .col-lg-3
            .alert.alert-success.text-center
                i.fa.fa-money(aria-hidden='true')
                b  Amount Loaned
                p
                    | #{data.AmountLoaned}
        .col-lg-3
            .alert.alert-info.text-center
                i.fa.fa-money(aria-hidden='true')
                b Expected Recovery Today
                P
                    | #{data.ExpectedRecovery}

        .col-lg-3
            .alert.alert-warning.text-center
                i.fa.fa-money(aria-hidden='true')
                b Actual Recovery Today
                p
                    | #{data.ActualRecovery}
```

am a newbie in JavaScript and need help ,Am pulling data from a database using nodejs and i want to represent a single Value of an object which is an array of objects(database tables data from the db ) how will i do this.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code? It's really hard to think about it without having any piece of code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Okey ,let me send the code

Comment: I have uploadedthe code ,The homepage controller is querying the database ,what i want is to represent a single element to the view ,from the queried data from the database